# Using Razor to set/get a session variable

Tags: c#, razor

I'm a front-end developer, so not used to razor and c# controller logic.

Our site is subject to that new standard to have a cookies disclaimer at the bottom of the site. It's on a sticky footer overlay, that will close when you click the [X]. The disclaimer should stay hidden as long as the session lasts.

So, clicking the [x] button on the footer closes the footer and triggers a function that set a session variable: DisclaimerSeen=true.

Then I'll write a show/hide condition into the footer overlay: If  DisclaimerSeen then (hide footer).

I am not entirely clear how a button talks to either Razor or C#. I know *what* to do, just not *how* to implement it.

Here is the button on the .cshtml page:

```
         <button type="button" class="close setCookieDisclaimer" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
```

and i'll wrap it in a condition:

```
@if (!DisclaimerSeen) {
    <div class="footbar>
         <button type="button" class="close setCookieDisclaimer" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
    </div>
}
```

(Actually, that's clumsy. I'll probably set a class to show/hide in in real-time. The above code would require a page refresh).

And here is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using GlobalRequest.Web.Models;
using GlobalRequest.Service;
using GlobalRequest.Facade;
using CMSGatewayFacade;

namespace GlobalRequest.Web.Controllers
{
    public class GlobalController : GlobalBaseController
    {
        public string caseManagerServiceBaseURL {
            ....
        }
    }
    public ActionResult Organization()
    {
        SelectedOrganization = null;
        return View(new OrganizationModel());
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: You're looking for either `<form>` or AJAX.

Comment: Shouldn't you store the user's acknowledgment in a cookie? Do you want to show them this message every time they visit your site?

Comment: We're going with closing the overlay is an acknowledgement. So this question is about technical implementation, not UX. Pretty sure it can be done without AJAX or a form.

Comment: Not if you want to store something in session it can't. If you just want to close the overlay, use Javascript; if you want to store to session, then use the aforementioned options.

Comment: Yeah. There was some confusion. you're right- client-side cookie is the way to go.